# Wall rot going on near the shower

Tags: shower, waterproofing, water-damage

There appears to be water damage outside the shower near the floor.  I'm not sure what is causing it. I could use some advise as to exactly what kind of research and/or repair is needed for next steps.  Is this a drywall issue?  Could sanding it down and repainting it be enough?  Anything I can do to stop the damage?

There is a little plastic runner that goes on the bottom of the shower.  I've replaced it before.  It has never worked well even new.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: the shower enclosure (frame) could use some new silicon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one- clean the calc build up with white vinegar till no deposits are visible.

Step 2- remove (scrape it out) all broken or loose silicon, and replace with fresh.

Step 3- use some silicone grease and put it on the rubber seals.

Next project:

The wood frame (dark color) is starting to rot at the bottom. Scrape off loose parts. Using spatula apply wood rot plaster specially made for that purpose. Paint over.

Next step:

The paint on the wall also needs some attention. Scrape loose material and paint over, using primer first.